# Mongodb scala driver custom conversion to JSON

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

If I am using "native" json support from mongodb oficial scala driver:

`val jsonText = Document(...).toJson()`

it produces json text with type prefixes for extended types:

```
{ "$oid" : "AABBb...." }   - for ObjectID, 
{ "$longNumber" : 123123  } - for Long and etc.
```

I want to avoid such type conversion and write directly just values for each type. Is it possible somehow to overwrite encoding behavior for some type?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `JsonWriter` and override `writeXXX` methods. For example, to customize date serialization you can use:

```
class CustomJsonWriter extends JsonWriter {
    public CustomJsonWriter(Writer writer) {
        super(writer);
    } 

    public CustomJsonWriter(Writer writer, JsonWriterSettings settings) {
        super(writer, settings);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doWriteDateTime(long value) {
        doWriteString(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME
            .withZone(ZoneId.of("Z"))
            .format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(value)));
    }
}
```

And then you can use the overridden version that way:

```
    public static String toJson(Document doc) {
        CustomJsonWriter writer = new CustomJsonWriter(new StringWriter(), new JsonWriterSettings());
        DocumentCodec encoder = new DocumentCodec();
        encoder.encode(writer, doc, EncoderContext.builder().isEncodingCollectibleDocument(true).build());
        return writer.getWriter().toString();
    }
```